# Maven project that depends on other project

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

After i've been through some stackoverflow questions and documents about maven pom.xml relations i am still confused.

I have a project with its own pom.xml

```
-src/MyProject
-src/MyProject/POM.XML
```

Now i need to include another 3rd Party project

```
-src/MyProject
-src/MyProject/POM.XML
-src/OtherProject
-src/OtherProject/POM.XML
```

I need now to tell Maven when its building the MyProject POM.XML the other POM.XML has to be processed and included.

**Reason:** I need not only the jar built from OtherProject as a dependency, but what is more important: i need all the dependencies (jars) from the OtherProject as well for MyProject (and i dont want to enter every jar as a dependency manually for MyProject which are already correctly defined in the OtherProjects POM.XML).

What are possible solutions to do this?

Comment: Did you simply add a dependency inside `MyProject` POM?

Comment: Maven poms do not work by 'including' them within each other; they instead create a hierarchy.. see http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/maven-tutorials/jboss-maven/maven-multi-module-tutorial

Comment: Also search about how to specify the modules in the MyProject pom. this will build your child project first before building your "MyProject"

Comment: The link by @ChrisK explains what I am trying to say see the <modules> tag .. :) :)

Comment: Hi, i tried adding modules to the MyProjects Pom.xml but Maven Eclipse Plugin told me that i had to change packaging form jar to pom? So i aborted this approach. Maybe i give it another try.

Comment: @Gobliins, don't abort. it's just what's supposed to happen.

Comment: Can i include every pom.xml as a module?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a *multi-module maven application* that consist of several projects (called "modules"). The multi-module application nests all the *projects* and the so-called master `pom.xml`, in which the application modules are defined. Each module will have to hold its own `pom.xml`, also.

So, your directory structure would like:

```
/application
|---/project1
|---/project2
|---pom.xml
```

The master `pom.xml` will define the application modules:

```
<project ...>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>project1</module>
        <module>project2</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencyManagement> ... </dependencyManagement>
    ...
</project>
```

Defined like this, `project1` will build before `project2`.

Comment: So in my example, i would create a project which adds both of my projects as modules? Or do you mean that i add the dependend project as module in my main project? (Because i would have a dependency from project2 to project1 but afaik modules should be independ form each other)

Comment: Yes, I meant to create a project that contains both of the projects.